# many activities with same content (adview, reward adview, functions...) how to avoid repeating code?

Tags: android

I have a gallery app, with some categories: animals, flowers... each gallery I created one activity, this activity in all galleries has the same content:

```
onCreate:
 tSpeak = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() { ...

 AdView adView = new AdView(MainActivity.this); ...

//some checks to change images:

if(fase == 1) { imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.flower1); ...
if(fase == 100) ...

some setOnClickListener

after that some onRewardedVideo functions, a next() function that will intent to the same activity to show next image on this gallery (`fase` + 1)
```

**What I'd like to know is, can I instead of repeating all this things (TextToSpeech, listeners, rewardedvideos functions, adview functions) just change the `if` checks in each activity gallery?** this is the only thing that will change in each activity gallery, and I don't want to use just one activity for all categories because in this case I may have more than 2000 `ifs` and it is not good to work.

I'd like to just inject in each category the `ifs` to set imageresources there, without need to copy all activity again and again in each category. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your common functionalities in a `BaseActivity` and extend your activities from this `BaseActivity`.

For the ifs conditional checking you can have a boolean field in your `BaseActivity` which you can override in your each subclass (In this case, your actual activities).

A better option could be having one activity only where your category is passed in the `Bundle`. Now based on your category, you can `switch` over the value and keeps your variations.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a single activity and pass a gallery ID as a parameter to your activity via an Intent extra.

You could get the image resource ids of the current gallery from a static map in your activity.

You could also use a ViewPager with one gallery per fragment, to enable your user to navigate quickly accross galleries.

Look at this for more info:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide